# accessing outer scope in jQuery callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, jquery-callback

I have a situation where I need a jQuery callback to work on a variable outside of it's scope. For the sake of simplicity, assume the following code:

```
$('#myBtn').on('click', function(e) {
    var num = 1;

    // assume this returns the following:
    // { success : true, num : 1 }
    $.getJSON('/api/get_number', {}, function(response) {
        if ( response.success ) {
            // here, num is unknown unless I define it as a
            // global variable
            num += response.num ;   
        }
    });

    console.log(num); // => want 2, get 1
});
```

I would like num to be available inside the callback function. What's a good way to do this without declaring global variables (declaring num outside the onclick function)? Is there a way to pass it as an argument without having to send it from the server? thanks.

Comment: `num` is successfully updated, but **after** you call `console.log(num)`. The issue is not about scope, Ajax is **asynchronous**. Move `console.log(num)` inside the callback and you will see. There exist many, many related questions already.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#myBtn').on('click', function(e) {
    var num = 1;

    // assume this returns the following:
    // { success : true, num : 1 }
    $.getJSON('/api/get_number', {}, function(response) {
        // get responce
        if ( response.success ) {
            // here, num is unknown unless I define it as a
            // global variable
            num += response.num ;   
            console.log(num); // you will get 2 here
        }
    });
    // responce havnt get ,you always get 1
    console.log(num); // => want 2, get 1
});
```